# Socket.IO -- ReferenceError: io is not defined, used to work on another website

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have always used the code below to do this, in another website it worked fine, but now it's not.

**server.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

var users = {};
console.log("Sever is now running");

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { 
    console.log("connection");
    socket.emit('connected');

});
```

The server seems to be fine, I think. It shows the console.log message anyways. Though the second console.log doesn't show up, but I just figured it was because of the error or whatever.

**data.js**

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin, {port:8080});

$(document).ready(function(){
    socket.on('connected', function () {    
        alert("A");
    });
});
```

Comment: do you get any error on server or client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client code (data.js) add 
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` before you set the socket.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem, however doing it exactly as you said didn't work. It only works if i do: "http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"

Is there a way to get rid of that? There must be, because my previous website didn't require any of this at all in the first place..